# Solr: group by child document field and include parent fields

Tags: solr, grouping, parent-child, solr8

Is there a way to group by a child document field and include the parent fields to the result?
Imagine you have

```
[
  {
    "id": "p1",
    "name": "parent 1",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "p1c1",
        "name": "child1_of_parent1",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": "p1c2",
        "name": "child2_of_parent1",
        "color": "yellow"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "p2",
    "name": "parent 2",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "p2c1",
        "name": "child1_of_parent2",
        "color": "yellow"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in a collection.

Now a query
/select?group=true&group.field=color&group.limit=10
returns

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "params":{
      "group.limit":"10",
      "group.field":"color",
      "group":"true"
    }
  },
  "grouped":{
    "color":{
      "matches":3,
      "groups":[
        {
          "groupValue":"red",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1,"docs":[
              {
                "id":"p1c1",
                "name":"child1_of_parent1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "groupValue":"yellow",
          "doclist":{"numFound":2,"docs":[
              {
                "id":"p1c2",
                "name":"child2_of_parent1"
              },
              {
                "id":"p2c1",
                "name":"child1_of_parent2"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I need a result that contains their parent fields as well, something like

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "params":{
      "group.limit":"10",
      "group.field":"color",
      "group":"true"
    }
  },
  "grouped":{
    "color":{
      "matches":3,
      "groups":[
        {
          "groupValue":"red",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1,"docs":[
              {
                "id":"p1c1",
                "name":"child1_of_parent1",
                "parent":{
                  "id": "p1",
                  "name": "parent 1",
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "groupValue":"yellow",
          "doclist":{"numFound":2,"docs":[
              {
                "id":"p1c2",
                "name":"child2_of_parent1",
                "parent":{
                  "id": "p1",
                  "name": "parent 1",
                }
              },
              {
                "id":"p2c1",
                "name":"child1_of_parent2",
                "parent":{
                  "id": "p2",
                  "name": "parent 2",
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm coming from relational databases, where this can easily be done. Hopefully there's a way in solr as well. I'm using solr 8.7.0

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is [subquery](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_subquery_). It satisfies the requirements, but the performance is what is to expect when you transfer a relational "join" to a document db.

It will definitely be a better idea to rework the datamodel to a flat structure.

Before I had to add a field in the child doc for the parent id (the default "*root*" doesn't work):

```
[
  {
    "id": "p1",
    "name": "parent 1",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "p1c1",
        "name": "child1_of_parent1",
        "color": "red",
        "parent_id": "p1"
      },
      {
        "id": "p1c2",
        "name": "child2_of_parent1",
        "color": "yellow",
        "parent_id": "p1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "p2",
    "name": "parent 2",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "p2c1",
        "name": "child1_of_parent2",
        "color": "yellow",
        "parent_id": "p2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I can query
/select?group=true&group.field=color&group.limit=10&fl=*%2Cparent%3A%5Bsubquery%5D&parent.q=%7B%21terms+f%3Did+v%3D%24row.parent_id%7D

and it returns

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "params":{
      "group.limit":"10",
      "group.field":"color",
      "group":"true",
      "fl":"*,parent:[subquery]",
      "parent.q":"{!terms f=id v=$row.parent_id}",
    }
  },
  "grouped":{
    "color":{
      "matches":3,
      "groups":[
        {
          "groupValue":"red",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1,"docs":[
              {
                "id":"p1c1",
                "name":"child1_of_parent1",
                "parent":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
                  "id": "p1",
                  "name": "parent 1",
                ]}
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "groupValue":"yellow",
          "doclist":{"numFound":2,"docs":[
              {
                "id":"p1c2",
                "name":"child2_of_parent1",
                "parent":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
                  "id": "p1",
                  "name": "parent 1",
                ]}
              },
              {
                "id":"p2c1",
                "name":"child1_of_parent2",
                "parent":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
                  "id": "p2",
                  "name": "parent 2",
                ]}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Feel free to comment if that reminds you at a better idea.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30126347)

Comment: That is actually the complete answer I am working with for now.

The performance topic I mentioned is just a side note that future copy cats should be aware of.